# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when retrieving data from database

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreach

I am attempting to retrieve data from two tables and echo the results out, the sql appears to be correct but it tells my the argument is invalid.
heres my code:

```
// Retrieve all information related to this post
    function get_post_data($post_id){

        //test the connection
        try{
            //connect to the database
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");
        //if there is an error catch it here
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            //display the error
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_id = $post_id';
        $result = $dbh->query( $sql );

        foreach($result as $row):

            echo $row['img_id'];

        endforeach;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$post_id` in your query won't be being expanded because the string is single quoted.

It should work better with:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_id = $post_id";
```

or:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_id = '.$post_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell PDO to throw errors:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

That will probably tell you what is happening (except for a potential problem when creating the pdo object the line before it...).

I would also recommend switching to prepared statements to avoid potential sql injection or malformed query problems.

And I hope that is not your real password...

Comment: Hi, no that isn't my real password. I tried using this prepared statement: $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_id = ?');
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $post_id);
  $result = $stmt->execute();

Comment: How do I use the error properties in that setattribute method?

Comment: @crm To use the error properties, you have to wrap all sql in a `try` - `catch` block, not just the connection part.